# How to invert the Toner layer in a Stamen map?

Tags: reactjs, gis, openlayers, raster, stamen-maps

I am trying to invert the toner layer here, and maybe add a color tint to it as well as you can see here on Map Stack : [http://mapstack.stamen.com/edit.html#toner[invert=1,tint=$1e88e5@100]/11/37.7547/-122.3513](http://mapstack.stamen.com/edit.html#toner%5Binvert=1,tint=$1e88e5@100%5D/11/37.7547/-122.3513)

Although, I'm not sure how would I use that url as a parameter since I don't see it reflect on the map instance.

The API in OpenLayers has no information on how to manipulate the Stamen map.

**The Code**

```
<TileLayer
id="nightmode"
title="Night Mode"
source={
  new Stamen({
     layer: 'toner',
     params: {
     layers: "",
     format: "image/png",
     tiled: true
   }
 })
}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenLayers 6 similar to the grayscale OSM in this example https://openlayers.org/en/main/examples/semi-transparent-layer.html you could specify a className for the layer and use an invert css filter https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-newton-mk9th?file=/main.js

An alternative would be to use a globalCompositeOperation similar to https://codesandbox.io/s/globalcompositeoperation-fktwf

Comment: Thank you very much
Didn't realize it can be changed through css selector